# Flask PyMongo connection error: Unknown option connect

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pymongo

I am running flask app which connects to MongoDB hosted at mlab. Here is the code snippet.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'my-db-name'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds061474.mlab.com:61474/<db-name>'
mongo = PyMongo(app)
```

When I run flask from terminal (after adding username:password and db name, I get follow error (screenshot below)[!:
`pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: Unknown option connect`
[image]

I am running:

```
Flask: 1.0.2
Flask-PyMongo: 2.2.0
Python: 3.7.0
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After quite a bit of debug, I was able to find issue. 
I removed package `flask-pymongo` and re-installed it and noticed following error which was the issue:
`flask-pymongo 2.2.0 has requirement PyMongo>=3.0, but you'll have pymongo 2.8.1 which is incompatible.`

So I added `PyMongo>=3.0` to my `requirements.txt` file before `flask-pymongo` and re-installed modules by running `pip install -r requirements.txt`